# gitlab install: ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: installation, gitlab

I try install gitlab.

> $ uname -a Linux serv1 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

I try execute this:

> sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

and i receive this:

> /usr/bin/gitlab-ctl: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

---

when i do so:

> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby ruby

from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ , and try sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure , i receive this:

> $ sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could
>   not find omnibus-ctl (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-4.0.0,
>   actionmailer-3.2.13, actionpack-4.0.0, actionpack-3.2.13,
>   activemodel-4.0.0, activemodel-3.2.13, activerecord-4.0.0,
>   activerecord-3.2.13, activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3,
>   activeresource-3.2.13, activesupport-4.0.0, activesupport-3.2.13,
>   arel-4.0.0, arel-3.0.2, atomic-1.1.14, builder-3.1.4, builder-3.0.0,
>   bundler-1.3.5, capybara-2.0.3, childprocess-0.3.9, coderay-1.0.9,
>   daemon_controller-1.1.5, erubis-2.7.0, ffi-1.9.0, hike-1.2.3,
>   i18n-0.6.5, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.0.3, json-1.8.0,
>   mail-2.5.4, metaclass-0.0.1, mime-types-1.25, minitest-4.7.5,
>   mocha-0.13.3, multi_json-1.8.1, mysql2-0.3.13, net-ldap-0.3.1,
>   nokogiri-1.5.10, passenger-4.0.20, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.5.2,
>   rack-1.4.5, rack-cache-1.2, rack-openid-1.4.0, rack-ssl-1.3.3,
>   rack-test-0.6.2, rails-4.0.0, rails-3.2.13, railties-4.0.0,
>   railties-3.2.13, rake-10.1.0, rdoc-4.0.1, rdoc-3.12.2,
>   ruby-openid-2.2.3, rubyzip-0.9.9, selenium-webdriver-2.35.1,
>   shoulda-3.3.2, shoulda-context-1.0.2, shoulda-matchers-1.4.1,
>   sprockets-2.10.0, sprockets-2.2.2, sprockets-rails-2.0.0, thor-0.18.1,
>   thread_safe-0.1.3, tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.15, tzinfo-0.3.38,
>   websocket-1.0.7, xpath-1.0.0, yard-0.8.7.2] (Gem::LoadError)    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'    from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:22:in`'

---

> $ whereis omnibus-ctl
>
> omnibus-ctl:

---

> $ file /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby:
>   ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
>   linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26,
>   BuildID[sha1]=0x1faedc58011582fcad5e464104104752d470ada1, not stripped

---

> $ ldd /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
>
> not a dynamic executable

---

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin$ ls -al
>
> ..
>
> -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   12285 Jul 22 14:10 ruby
>
> ..

Comment: I had the same issue on gitlab: the problem was my `$PATH`: the local installed ruby was overriding the gitlab's embedded ruby. Look at your `$PATH` and try to change the order

Comment: My PATH is: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games .  What order has to be?